# Difference between defining configuration as Properties and Map object

Tags: java, apache-kafka

What is the difference between configuring the configuration of Kafka as `Properties` object and `Map` object. For example :

```java
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
```

and

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("key.serializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer");
props.put("schema.registry.url", url);
```

Comment: Don't think there is much different, if I remember vaguely, these options are there to support different languages and interacting from shell etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a difference other than you could specify Object or String as the value of the Map.

There's an internal method called `propsToMap` that converts the Properties object to a Map eventually